# Wordpress site in subdirectory, logout function failing

Tags: wordpress, logout, directory-structure

We have Wordpress site in the root of our domain. A translation plugin we use appends the domain with (in our case for Czech) /cs - this means we can run more than one translation but use the same database and wp-content as the main English website.

However, the added /cs causes the logout function to fail as it tries to use the current directory as the basis for where the actual site content is being pulled from.

The actual code being used is `<?php echo wp_logout_url( $redirect ); ?>`. We have tried a simple HTML href but the logout link is dynamic and requires a unique nonce value to validate the command.

Do you have any ideas for how we can have a logout button that uses the actual site address (mywebsite.com) rather than with the added 'directory' (mywebsite.com/cs). I have thus far been unable to edit the **wp_logout_url** to add a / before it. Any ideas?

Example links:
Correct: 
`http://www.mywebsite.com/backend?action=logout&redirect_to=index.php&_wpnonce=d8eaf8594a`

Incorrect, resulting in 404 ERROR:
`http://www.mywebsite.com/cs/backend?action=logout&redirect_to=index.php&_wpnonce=d8eaf8594a`

Actual code being used (relevant logout code is the #bawlogout# part):

```
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'bawllm_setup_nav_menu_item' );
function bawllm_setup_nav_menu_item( $item )
{
    global $pagenow;
    if( $pagenow!='nav-menus.php' && !defined('DOING_AJAX') && isset( $item->url ) && strstr( $item->url, '#baw' ) != '' ){
        $item_url = substr( $item->url, 0, strpos( $item->url, '#', 1 ) ) . '#';
        $item_redirect = str_replace( $item_url, '', $item->url );
        switch( $item_url ) {
            case '#bawloginout#' :  
                                    $item_redirect = explode( '|', $item_redirect );
                                    if( count( $item_redirect ) != 2 ) 
                                        $item_redirect[1] = $item_redirect[0];
                                    for( $i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++ ):
                                        if( $item_redirect[$i] == '%actualpage%')
                                            $item_redirect[$i] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                                    endfor;
                                    $item->url = is_user_logged_in() ? wp_logout_url( $item_redirect[1] ) : wp_login_url( $item_redirect[0] );
                                    $item->title = bawllm_loginout_title( $item->title ) ; break;
            case '#bawlogin#' :     $item->url = wp_login_url( $item_redirect ); break;
            case '#bawlogout#' :    $item->url = wp_logout_url( $item_redirect ); break;
            case '#bawregister#' :  if( is_user_logged_in() ) $item->title = '#bawregister#'; else $item->url = site_url( '/wp-login.php?action=register', 'login' ); break;
        }
        $item->url = esc_url( $item->url );
    }
    return $item;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I took the easy way out and use a Redirect 301 in .htaccess to redirect that logout link with /cs/ to /

Answer (score 1):

I would put the URL into a variable so that you can perform a regular expression on it, for example:

```
<?php

$url       = wp_logout_url( $redirect );
$fixed_url = preg_replace("/stuff_to_find/", "stuff_to_replace", $url);

?>
```

Comment: That is a great idea Moov Tony. I'm a bit unsure of preg_replace though and inserted it into the code shown in my original post... the line looks like this `case '#bawlogout#' :  $item->url = wp_logout_url( $item_redirect ); preg_replace("/cs/", "/"); break;` but the following error shows (pertaining to that specific line): `Warning: preg_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given in...` - can you help with the specific code?

Comment: two things to note: 1. you need to perform preg_replace on a variable, 2. the third parameter that you need pass in is the original URL ($url).  For example:    $fixed_url = preg_replace("/cs/", "/", $url);

Comment: also you may get unexpected results with a regular expression that only looks for "cs" as it is very generic. It would be best to make it more specific if at all possible.

Comment: It is only used for this one button and that's the only difference in the URLs unfortunately. I tried `case '#bawlogout#' :  $item->url = wp_logout_url( $item_redirect ); $fixed_url = preg_replace("/cs/", "/", $item); break;` with the error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string in...`

Comment: if that's the case you neeed to call strval() on $item:    case '#bawlogout#' : $item->url = wp_logout_url( $item_redirect ); $fixed_url = preg_replace("/cs/", "/", strval($item)); break;

Comment: Same error unfortunately about the same line: "Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string in..."

Comment: Sorry try:  --->     case '#bawlogout#' : $item->url = wp_logout_url( $item_redirect ); $fixed_url = preg_replace("/cs/", "/", strval($item->url)); break;

Comment: Thanks Moov - no error this time... but no desired behaviour either. The link remains as www.mydomain.com/cs/